# How do I inherit all variable from a parent class to a base class having an init function?

Tags: python

I know that I can inherit handpicked variables from a parent class by adding their name in a super() function as follows:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname

class Student(Person):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    super().__init__(fname, lname)

x = Student("myfirstname", "andlast")
```

But I need to do two other things:

1. Inherit all the attributes from the parent class without mentioning each's name, so I can just call them as self.attrbname.
2. After doing no.1, add more attributes in the child class through the **init** function.

So, what am I supposed to write for the above tasks?

Comment: Please can you give an example of how you want to *use* your `Student` class. For example, are these other attributes meant to appear in the argument list or would you still use `x = Student("myfirstname", "andlast")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__init__` is a regular function, and [has the same capabilities as any other](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) – use `*args` and `**kwargs` to forward arguments anonymously. Additional parameters can be defined explicitly to not pass them on and allow using them directly.

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname

class Student(Person):
  # *args/**kwargs receive unspecified arguments
  def __init__(self, *args, semester, **kwargs):
    #                v pass on any unspecified arguments
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #                v use explicitly specified argument
    self.semester = semester

x = Student("myfirstname", "andlast", semester=6)
```